# web api2 RESTful GET not returning get by id

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

not quite sure what I am missing

standard webapiconfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MROVendorWebAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

pretty basic controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MROVendorWebAPI.Models;

namespace MROVendorWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class VSMRICSController : ApiController
    {



        public IEnumerable<DB2VsmRicRecord> GetDB2VsmRicRecords()
        {
            string ErrorDescription = "";
            DB2VsmRicCollection myDB2VsmRicCollection = new DB2VsmRicCollection();
            if (myDB2VsmRicCollection.CreateCollection(ref ErrorDescription))
            {
                return myDB2VsmRicCollection.oDB2VsmRicList;
            }
            return null;
        }



        public DB2VsmRicRecord GetDB2VsmRicRecord(string ric)
        {
            string ErrorDescription = "";
            DB2VsmRicCollection myDB2VsmRicCollection = new DB2VsmRicCollection();
            if (myDB2VsmRicCollection.CreateCollection(ref ErrorDescription))
            {
                return myDB2VsmRicCollection.oDB2VsmRicList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Ric == ric);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

using /api/VSMRICS  works correctly and returns the entire collection
and using /api/VSMRICS?RIC=SAH  works correctly and returns just one record however /api/VSMRICS/SAH returns the entire collection.  not sure why that is do I need to add some sort of routing to this method in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

duh never mind it needs to be

```
public DB2VsmRicRecord GetDB2VsmRicRecord(string id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In conventional routing it search for the RouteParameter which is mentioned in route as id.

Here you can also change the route like below:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ric}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

For supporting your API:

```
public DB2VsmRicRecord GetDB2VsmRicRecord(string ric)
{
   string ErrorDescription = "";
   DB2VsmRicCollection myDB2VsmRicCollection = new DB2VsmRicCollection();
   if (myDB2VsmRicCollection.CreateCollection(ref ErrorDescription))
   {
      return myDB2VsmRicCollection.oDB2VsmRicList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Ric == ric);
   }
   return null;
}
```